# Listbox1 & listbox2 to differnt columns in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

i have searched for an answer and still cant find anything so , i would like to ask

in vb.net how would i go about putting the data from listbox1 and listbox2 into separate columns in a datagridview?

I can add only to the first column or first and second from one source

Im very stuck and starting to pull my hair out

Thanks in advance

Comment: might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29r1-NRDD10

Comment: very difficult to help without code.  See: [Ask]